# Bcrypt hashing not supported with Laravel 4 and PHP 5.3.6 in MAMP 2.0.1

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I'm trying  to execute the following line with Laravel,

```
Hash::make('asdqwe');
```

But it fails with this error:

```
Bcrypt hashing not supported.
```

I've checked my `php.ini` and `extension=mcrypt.so` is enabled, and `phpinfo()` would show this:

[image: mcrypt in phpinfo()]

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 4 requires PHP 5.3.7 minimum with the MCrypt extension installed

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/installation#server-requirements